# Copy files over SSH failed "Error: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Im trying to copy files over SSH, im using the same SSH Service Connection and it's just fine with other SSH tasks but copying files seems to run into trouble, Heres what it looks when i monitor for user logins

```
 sshd[32240]: Accepted publickey for azurePPL1 from 13.69.175.211 port 1984 ssh2: ECDSA SHA256:0...
```

and this seems to be fine but it's not?

heres the error Azure Pipelines is throwing

```
Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format.
```

Now i wouldve suspected my SSH Service Connection configuration but since other ssh work im not sure what it could be

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its now clear that the Azure Task is using an old version of [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2)
where Ed25519 keys are not supported which results in this issue so ill just have to use RSA for now.

Answer (score 2):

> Using the same SSH Service Connection and it's just fine with other
>   SSH tasks but copying files seems to run into trouble

Since it's all work for other SSH task to use the same SSH Service Connection just `Copy Files over SSH` has failed, it means there's no error on your SSH key pair and connection. In fact, the issue relevant with the parser which used in  `Copy Files over SSH` task.

See the function about the script of the copy file task which open source in github: [function run in CopyFileOverSSH.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CopyFilesOverSSHV0/copyfilesoverssh.ts#L100), and the definition of class `SshHelper`: [sshhelper.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/CopyFilesOverSSHV0/sshhelper.ts#L10). In fact, the `Copy Files over SSH` task uses [Ssh2 npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) for the SSH connection and verify, the error message you are facing is coming from there. For the copy file task itself, it does not do any key parsing.

About key parsing, see this source function: [keyParser.js](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2-streams/blob/master/lib/keyParser.js#L1326). Locate to line 1447, you will see that it is the error message you received in the task of Azure Devops.

As I know, from the task `v0.148` is using ssh2 library `v0.8`, but now ssh2 library has been [updated into v0.8.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2).

So to solve this issue Please regenerate the key pair with the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM`, to force `ssh-keygen` to export as `PEM` format. Thus the key can work in the copy file task.

Comment: Yeah, that's the case for RSA keys but not for ECDSA, hopefully the newer version will become available soon

Comment: @Tero, you can raise ticket in Developer Community or github. Thus our Product Group will notice this issue which caused by the library version not the latest. Developer Community can directly get response/contact from our Product Group.

Comment: I already made an [issue at github](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11443) but will try to make one in Developer Community.